# Happy.js with radio buttons using input name instead of input id for awesomeform.ishappy

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I would appreciate all the help I could get!

I'm validating a form client-side using Happy.js

The first input that I want validated is a radiobutton with yes/no. The ID of this input is tied to a javascript function hide/show two divs, therefore I can't change the id to be the same for happy.js:

```
<input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="Yes" aria-required="true" required/><label for ="id_radio1">Yes</label>
<input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="name_radio2" value="No" aria-required="true" required//><label for ="id_radio2">No</label>
```

My happy.js script is as follows, The first field #id_radio1 is the code in question:

```
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#awesomeForm').isHappy({
          fields: {
            // reference the field you're talking about, probably by `id`
            // but you could certainly do $('[name=name]') as well.
            '#id_radio1': {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please specify Gas Spring Type'
            },      
            '#qnty': {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please specify # of Units'
            },
            '#street': {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please enter your Street',
            },
             '#city': {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please enter your City',
             },
             '#state': {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please enter your State/Province',
            },
             '#country': {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please enter your Country',
            },
             '#zip': {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please enter your Zip/Postal Code',
            },
             '#email': {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please enter a valid Email Address',
              test: happy.email // this can be *any* function that returns true or false
            },
          }
        });
      }); 
    </script>
```

Thank you for your help.

For your reference, this is the script for DIV switch:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('#div1,#div2').hide();
                    $('#id_radio1').click(function () {
                       $('#div2').hide('fast');
                       $('#div1').show('fast');
                });
                $('#id_radio2').click(function () {
                      $('#div1').hide('fast');
                      $('#div2').show('fast');
                 });
});</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a custom function to validate the radio buttons and reference them using the input name. Something like this should work:

```
$('#awesomeForm').isHappy({
      fields: {
          'input[name=name_radio1]':{
              required: 'sometimes',
              message: 'Please select a value',
              test: function(){ 
                  return $('input[name=name_radio1]').is(':checked');
              },
          }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The name should be the same for both radio buttons, ID can never be the same.